# How to split a text file at certian keywords using strcmp in C?

Tags: c, split

I am able to split the file according to a certain number of lines. However when I try to use strcmp to write a new file at a certain word "Turn" I am unable to do so. 
The goal of this program is to read a text file and write multiple text files starting a new file at the word "Turn". 
In the code I printed out the value of the strcmp(line, "Turn") and none returns 0.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

  int main() {
  FILE * ptr_readfile;
  FILE * ptr_writefile;
  char line[128]; /* or some other suitable maximum line size */
  char fileoutputname[15];
  int filecounter = 1;


  ptr_readfile = fopen("zion.txt", "r");
  if (!ptr_readfile)
   return 1;

  sprintf(fileoutputname, "book_part%d", filecounter);
  ptr_writefile = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");

  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr_readfile) != NULL) {
   printf("im in the file: %s",line);
   printf("VALUE %d:  " , strcmp(line, "Turn"));  
     if(strcmp(line, "Turn") ==0 ) {   //this cmp statment is not being met
    fclose(ptr_writefile);
    filecounter++;
    sprintf(fileoutputname, "book_part%d", filecounter);
    ptr_writefile = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");

    if (!ptr_writefile)
     return 1;
   }
   fprintf(ptr_writefile, "%s", line);
  }
  fclose(ptr_readfile);
  return 0;
 }
```

this is the output:

```
im in the file: Turn
VALUE 10:  im in the file: When the Lord turned again the captivity of Zion,
VALUE 3:  im in the file: We were like them that dream,
VALUE 3:  im in the file: We were like them that dream.
VALUE 3:  im in the file: 2
VALUE -34:  im in the file: Then was our mouth filled with laughter,
VALUE -13:  im in the file: And our tongue with singing:
VALUE -19:  im in the file: Then said they among the nations,
VALUE -13:  im in the file: The Lord hath done great things,
VALUE -13:  im in the file: The Lord hath done great things for them.
VALUE -13:  im in the file:   The Lord hath done great things for us;
VALUE -52:  im in the file: Whereof we are glad.
VALUE 3:  im in the file: The Lord hath done great things for us;
VALUE -13:  im in the file:   Whereof we are glad.
VALUE -52:  im in the file: 3
VALUE -33:  im in the file: Turn
VALUE 10:  im in the file: again our captivity, O Lord, as the streams,
VALUE 13:  im in the file: As the streams in the south,
VALUE -19:  im in the file: As the streams in the south.
VALUE -19:  im in the file: 4
VALUE -32:  im in the file: They that sow in tears shall reap in joy,
VALUE -13:  im in the file: They that sow in tears shall reap in joy.
VALUE -13:  im in the file: 5
VALUE -31:  im in the file: Turn
VALUE 10:  im in the file: He that goeth forth and weepeth,
VALUE -12:  im in the file: Bearing precious seed, shall doubtless,
VALUE -18:  im in the file: Come again with rejoicing,
VALUE -17:  im in the file: Come again with rejoicing,
VALUE -17:  im in the file: Bringing his sheaves with him.
VALUE -18:  im in the file:   The Lord hath done great things for us;
VALUE -52:  im in the file: Whereof we are glad.
VALUE 3:  im in the file: The Lord hath done great things for us;
VALUE -13:  im in the file:   Whereof we are glad.
VALUE -52:  im in the file: 6
VALUE -30:  im in the file: Turn
VALUE 10:  im in the file: When the Lord turned again the captivity of Zion,
VALUE 3:  im in the file: We were like them that dream,
VALUE 3:  im in the file: We were like them that dream.
VALUE 3:
```

Comment: `fgets()` will include the newline at the end of the line it reads (if there is one).  You need to account for that somehow (assuming you're looking for a line with only the text "Turn" on it).

Comment: Every time the word turn appears it should have a value of 0

Comment: Yes i just added the output to make it a more understandable.

Comment: An easy fix would be to compare to `"Turn\n"` instead of `"Turn"`, which should work if there are no other characters (like trailing spaces) on the "Turn" line and it's not the last line of the file (without a newline).  Otherwise you could null the last char of the string read by `fgets()`, if it's `== '\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dividing line only has `Turn` in the line, (`i.e without leading or trailing spaces`), then you need to change your strcmp as below:

You are doing:

```
...
printf("VALUE %d:  " , strcmp(line, "Turn"));  
if(strcmp(line, "Turn") ==0 ) {   //this cmp statment is not being met
...
```

Instead you should compare with `"Turn\n"` because `fgets()` will capture the newline `(\n)` character also in `line`. So you should be doing

```
...
printf("VALUE %d:  " , strcmp(line, "Turn\n"));  
if(strcmp(line, "Turn\n") ==0 ) {   //this cmp should work if no leading or trailing space
...
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! 3 hours of wondering what I was doing wrong glad it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

After running your code it seems you just need to put a \n after turn.